# How to change my advanced search style?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, search

I have many categories and sub-categories. In any sub-category i have many products with attributes.

I want to change my advanced search style like this :

> My categories are displayed as dropdown.
>
> My sub-categories are displayed too as dropdown.
>
> Only product's attribute are displayed according to category.

For example :

I have computer category (parent) and in this category i have many other sub-categories like laptop , device .... (child) and in laptop i have many laptop's product and any laptop i assign to it many attribute like (Processor, Cache Memory, System Memory (RAM) ...)

I want to change my advanced search style like that :

when i select computer categories in dropdown, the sub-categories dropdown must display me laptop,device ... and when i select for exemple laptop i want that to display me Processor, Cache Memory, System Memory (RAM) fields for my search.

Any ideas or informations can help me to realize that?
Thanks

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking here.

Comment: I explain with an exemple what i want to do Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly sure what you are trying to do?

Do you mean products can be filtered on the categor page based on attributes?
If so you may want to anchor your category and said the product attribute to filter within the admin panel

Adam

Comment: I want the attributes of the product will be displayed after the selected categories

Comment: At which page:
www.domainname.com/categoryname
or
www.domainname.com/catalogsearch/advanced

Comment: www.domainname.com/catalogsearch/advanced

Comment: Okay, in which case go to:

Your admin panel -> catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes

Find the attribute you require e.g. ram, hard drive space etc.
Go into the attribute, select 'use in advanced search' to yes.

Comment: but it show me all attributes of all categories in the same page. I want to display only attributes of the category selected

Comment: Hi Amirov, apologies about not being able to help, Im not sure if you can edit this via a normal installation, I think you could potentially require a custom development into your Magento store.